# JSON to Pojo Converter Online jsonschema2pojo

Tags: java, android, json, jsonschema2pojo

I am using this [site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) since last one year.

I have done some kind of configuration on google Chorme(in my last system).

It was working well in my previous system. but this [Site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) is not working without that configuration in my others system. Please anyone share that configuration steps.

Comment: what configuration ?

Comment: I have done some configuration in Google Chorme to get the POJO. I had one doc file which had steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8634-robopojogenerator

If you are working on JetBrains product, you can check this plugin for an android studio you will not be required to go to website

Comment: I have added Plugin of RoboPojo but i am not getting option of Generate Pojo option